# Estoy iniciando en python, y debo calcular un porcentaje

Tags: python

*Debo hacer un programa para calcular el porcentaje de animales con un numero especifico de edades, pero no sé como crearlo correctamente, y esto es lo que tengo

```
#porcentaje zoologo
        def cantidad (numero):
        def nom (nombre):
        input("Ingrese el nombre del animal");
        while cantidad (numero)<-0:
        if nom :"elefante"
     
       input("ingrese la cantidad de elefantes de 0 a 1 año");
       (porcentajeuno<-(cantidad/20)*100);
       input("ingrese la cantidad de elefantes de 2 años");
       porcentajedos<-(cantidad/20)*100;
       input("ingrese cantidad de elefantes de 3 años o mas");
       porcentajetres<-(cantidad/20)*100;
       print("el porcentaje de animales de 0 a 1 año es ", porcentajeuno);
       print("el porcentaje de animales de 2 años es", porcentajedos);
       print("el porcentaje de animales de 3 años o mas es", porcentajetres);*
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es la duda concreta?

Comment: Tengo estas instrucciones...Un zoólogo pretende determinar el porcentaje de
animales que hay en las siguientes categorías de edades:
De 0 a 1 año, de más de 1 año y menos de 3 años, y de 3 o más
años. El zoológico todavía no está seguro del animal que va a
estudiar. Sí se decide por elefantes solo tomara una muestra de 20 de
ellos; sí se decide por jirafas, tomara 15 muestras y sí son chimpancés
tomara 40.

Comment: Si el animal no se encuentra en esa lista, el sistema imprimirá en
pantalla que el animal es desconocido.
Al finalizar el programa imprimirá en pantalla los porcentajes por
edades del animal seleccionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a un script similar a esto:

```
print("Escriba el nombre del animal")
animal = input()

print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 0 a 1 año");
uno = int(input())
print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 2 año");
dos = int(input())

print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 3 años o mas");
tres = int(input())

total = uno+dos+tres;

print(f"Total de {animal} es: " + str(total));
print("el porcentaje de animales de 0 a 1 año es :" + str((uno/total)*100) );
print("el porcentaje de animales de 2 años es :" + str((dos/total)*100) );
print("el porcentaje de animales de 3 años o mas es: " + str((tres/total)*100) );
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto me funciona perfectamente, de verdad gracias.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una respuesta que solo es código difícilmente será fácil de comprender a otros usuarios, considera editar y explicar tu aporte

Comment: @user200694 si te sirvió me respuesta, favor indicar que la respuesta fue útil. Saludos